# CodeIgniter test error pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating custom error pages in CodeIgniter, nothing fancy, just a simple change to the default pages to match the overall style.

It's a piece of cake to test the 404 and database error pages by simply pointing to non-exiting controlled or creating a flawed query.
Now, does anyone know what do I have to break in order to test the error_php and error_general pages?

Thank you

Comment: I think http://php.quicoto.com/how-to-create-a-404-page-in-codeigniter/ link might help you

Comment: I may not have explained myself properly. I know how to create custom error pages. I also know how to test 404 (index.php/non-existing-controller) or db error (select * from non_existing_table). What I don't know is how can I simulate php or general error and trigger the display of error pages making sure it all works as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While digging through the Codeigniter core I found the `show_php_error` in the `CI_Exceptions` class shows the `error_php` view. To test this you could create a test page where you [trigger a php error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php). The function that is available everywhere called `show_error` shows the `error_general` view.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function page_404() {
   $this->load->view("404");
}

$this->load->view('includes/meta_header',array('meta_title'=>'404 Page not found','meta_desc'=>'404 Page not found','meta_keywords'=>'404 Page',));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your routes.php

```
$route['404_override'] = 'error';
```

Your error.php controller

```
<?php 
class Error extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 

    public function index() 
    { 
        $this->output->set_status_header('404'); 
        $data['content'] = 'error_404'; // View name 
        $this->load->view('error-404',$data);//loading in my template 
    } 

} 
?>
```